# Laravel Live wire increment decrement is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I am putting steps functionality in my Todo list project.

I had created a composer for the livewire.

Also included `@livewireStyles` and
`@livewireScripts` both in the header and the footer.

Here, my **Increment control** does not work

***1) create.blade.php***

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('todo.store')}}" class="py-5" >
    @csrf

    <div class="py-1">
        <input type="text" name="title" class="px-2 py-2 border rounded" placeholder="Title">
    </div>
    ......
          
    @livewire('step')

    <div>
        <input type="text" name="stpe" class="px-2 py-2 border rounded" placeholder="Describe Steps">
    </div>
</form>
```

***2) step.blade.php***

```
<div>
    <div class="flex-justify-center pb-4 px-4">
                    
        <h2 class="text-lg pb-4">Add Stpes for task</h2>
        <i wire:click="increment" class ="fas fa-plus px-2 py-1 cursor-pointer "></i>
    </div>  

    {{$steps}}
</div>
```

***3) step.php***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Step extends Component
{
    public $steps = 0;

    public function increment()
    {
        $this->steps++;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.step');
    }
}
```

After performing this code my '+' icon cannot perform the increment operation, please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your code looks ok, make sure you are using it on laravel server i.e. `php artisan serve` command's platform: http://127.0.0.1:8000